# Como subtrair horas de uma data em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma variável que recebe a data atual e preciso subtrair horas dessa data.

```
var data = new Date();
```

Como **subtraio horas** dessa data?

Comment: quantas horas exatamente?

Comment: qualquer quantidade. Pode ser 5, 6, tanto faz

Comment: você não quer formatar a date primeiro?

Comment: Isso eu já fiz. Só não estava conseguindo a subtração das horas rs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

faça uma combinação de `setHours` com `getHours`.

```js
Date.prototype.addHours = function (value) {
  this.setHours(this.getHours() + value);
}

var data = new Date();
console.log(data);

data.addHours(-30);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: @SamirBraga, adicionei a função.

Comment: Agora está mais do que flexível, gostei.

Comment: Exatamente o que eu precisava!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode obter usando o getTime().

Então subtraia em milissegundos o quando deseja retornar.

```
// Defina o quanto quer voltar:

var Dia = 0;
Dia = Dia*60*60*24

var Hora = 1;
Hora = Hora*60*60;

var Minuto = 30;
Minuto = Minuto*60

var Segundos = 0;
Segundos = Segundos*1;

unix = new Date().getTime() - ((Dia+Hora+Minuto+Segundos)*1000);
resultado = new Date(unix);
```

**Demonstração:**

```js
$('input').on('keydown, keyup', function(){
      
    var Dia = $('[name=Dia]').val() !== '' ? parseInt($('[name=Dia]').val())*60*60*24 : 0;
    
    var Hora = $('[name=Hora]').val() !== '' ? parseInt($('[name=Hora]').val())*60*60 : 0;
    
    var Minuto = $('[name=Minutos]').val() !== '' ? parseInt($('[name=Minutos]').val())*60 : 0;
    
    var Segundos = $('[name=Segundos]').val() !== '' ? parseInt($('[name=Segundos]').val())*1 : 0;
        
    unix = new Date().getTime() - ((Dia+Hora+Minuto+Segundos)*1000);
    $('x').text(new Date(unix));
    
});

$('x').text(new Date());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Dias: <input type="number" name="Dia" value="0"></label> <br><label>Hora: <input type="number" name="Hora" value="0"></label> <br><label>Minutos: <input type="number" name="Minutos" value="0"></label> <br><label>Segundos: <input type="number" name="Segundos" value="0"></label> <br><x></x>
```